# Need a hint for convergence of alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

So I have this following sum $1-\frac{\pi^2}{2!} + \frac{\pi^4}{4!} - \frac{\pi^6}{6!} +   \space  ... \space $ 
Now obviously this is equal to the following infinite sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

But what is the limit of that sum? How do I go about finding what an alternating series converges to?

Comment: If you replace $\pi$ with $x$, does the series somehow look familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cos{\pi}=-1$$